# Pressing power button destroys activity and recreates - android

Tags: android, android-activity

Ok, I'm a little confused so here's some info: Galaxy Note 4, 4.4.4 fingerprint lock enabled. Screen timeout 10 minutes. I'm calling an activity TimerActivity from an activity MainActivity (onCreate) using:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

If I press the power button to turn off the screen (in less the the 10 minute timeout) I get:

```
TimerActivity onDestroy
TimerActivity onCreate
TimerActivity onResume
```

I'm ok with the onCreate/onResume sequence but I'm confused why it's destroying the activity and then creating it BUT it doesn't touch MainActivity. I've tried various addFlags in starting the TimerActivity but I cannot simply get an onResume from TimerActivity (which is my end goal).

UPDATE:

Ok I figured it had something to do with the lockscreen so:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

This preserves the TimerActivity.

Comment: Do you have don't keep activities in the developer options turned on?

Comment: Does the onPause get called in MainActivity?

Comment: Gabe: no I don't. Addict: Yes onPause gets called starting TimerActivity